# RGB artifact in the output of neural network

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, artifacts

I have a GAN with a simple encoder-decoder as a base. I have tested different combinations of loss functions (adversarial, L1, MSE, perceptual loss using pre-trained VGG16). The use case is filling in missing information (semantic inpainting) in a panorama. The network is based on the DeepFillv2 paper. See here: https://github.com/zhaoyuzhi/deepfillv2

However, my problem is that the higher I prioritize the adversarial loss or perceptual loss, the larger artifacts become visible like in the following images:

[image: Output of inpained panorama]

[image: Output of the artifact with different loss weights]

Structures are visible but with these RGB shifts. Has anyone had this problem before? Does anyone have any tips on what I could try? I had changed the normalization so far and tried different data sets.

Comment: looks slightly like [these artifacts](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/)

Comment: I know these artifacts from overlapping because of the stride. Although it does not look like these checkerboard errors, I can go for adjusting the stride. Maybe it helps.